# How does Mountain Lion authenticate with Twitter w/o using OAuth?

Tags: macos, twitter

I was kind of confused when I wasn't redirected to the Twitter page, to allow ML using my Twitter account for several things. In this case I had to input my username + password in the pure Mac gui and it just works.

How?! Basic Auth was disabled a few months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter removed basic auth, yes, but it didn't remove Username/Password auth.

See their documentation on [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth).

In a nutshell, you collect the user's username and password, and on successful verification, store the OAuth token and *discard the username and password*.

xAuth is explicitly allowed for certain applications, approved only from Twitter. It's not a stretch to say that Twitter would have approved Apple's request to use this in a heartbeat. The lack of ability to access Direct Messages via xAuth is limiting, but ultimately not relevant given the level of Apple's integration.